# How to set python installed path?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

My python 2.7 was installed in /usr/local/lib.
If I type  `which python2.7`, I can have `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`.
Then I set PYTHONPATH in ~/.bashrc as

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/bin/python2.7:$PYTHONPATH"
```

I like to install pip and virtual environment.
Then tried as

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev python-virtualenv
```

When looking for python in `/usr/lib` I found the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-dev is already the newest version.
python-pip is already the newest version.
python-virtualenv is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 362 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2) ...
python2.7: can't open file '/usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package python2.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I set python path properly?

EDIT:
My echo $PATH gave

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

echo $PYTHONPATH gave

```
/home/coie/Softwares/apollocaffe/python:/usr/local/bin/python2.7:
```

Comment: Just verifying, you did mean `~/.bashrc` and not `~/bashrc`, right?

Comment: Sorry ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 1):

I deleted all python installed in `/usr/local` using `>sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python* or libpython*`. Those in bin and share folder are also cleaned.
Then since all program looked for python inside `/usr`, the installation path is set to `sudo ./configure --prefix = /usr`

Answer (score 0):

According to https://askubuntu.com/a/250935/610294:

Try appending to PYTHONPATH instead of overwriting it completely.

Read: replace your line you added to bashrc with this:

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/bin/python2.7`

Comment: Yes I put the path behind

Comment: In the comment I linked, that thread also mentions about the script folder. Have you tried that? (`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/bin/python2.7/Scripts`)

Answer (score 0):

type setenv PATH "$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python" and press Enter.
or
 type export ATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python" and press Enter.